# Error when using "ng new" (angular cli)

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

I'm using mac, after install of angular cli (uninstall, clean cache, install -g) I receive on all ng functions this error, 
please help, tried to google it but couldn't find solution.

sudo ng --version / ng new PROG

```
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                     ^

TypeError: path must be a string
    at TypeError (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Function.Version.fromProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:87:31)
    at Function.Version.isPreWebpack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:111:31)
    at Function.Version.assertPostWebpackVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade
```